Localic slices of an étendue
An étendue is a Grothendieck topos $\mathcal{E}$ containing a well-supported object $A$ such that $\mathcal{E}/A$ is localic. This does not imply that all slices are localic (for example, the topos of directed graphs is a non-localic étendue). However, is there a characterization of all the well supported objects whose slices are indeed localic?
Additionally, I would like to ask for an intuition of what it means for an slice to be localic, how does that property tells us something about the topos $\mathcal{E}$?

I think $\mathcal{E} / A$ being localic would just mean that every object of $\mathcal{E}$ with a given morphism to $A$ can be generated under colimits by subobjects of $A$, right?
